# How to print data in a ListView using ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

**Updated**

I'm trying to print the data retrieved from the database on a list view. For a while my application print for each data in the database, a row on the list view. So if there are 10 data in the database, the app prints 10 rows, corresponding to each row of the database. Here is a view of how it is being printed.

The new image of how it looks now:

[image]

But, it is not printing the data as I want. I want to print a column of the row in a specific text view, but it doesnt show anything.

So the activity RatedCalss calls the method `selectTopCalls()` and makes a List receive the list that this method returns. And then I pass this list to the listAdapter.

Well I have this activity named **RatedCalls.java**:

```
public class RatedCalls extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "RatedCalls";
private CallDataHelper cdh;
private ListView listview;
private ArrayList<String> ratedCallsList;
private MyListAdapter listAdapter;
private View view;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "calling from onCreate()");
    cdh = new CallDataHelper(this);

    startService(new Intent(this, RatedCallsService.class));

    setBasicContent();

}

public void setBasicContent() {
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);     

    ratedCallsList = this.cdh.selectTopCalls();     

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ratedCallsList size: " + ratedCallsList.size());        
    listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, this, R.id.list_view, ratedCallsList);
    listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);   
   }
}
```

I have this class, a ListAdapter class named **MyListAdapter.java**:

```
    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter { //--CloneChangeRequired

    private ArrayList mList;
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity; 
    private int selectedPos = -1;   // init value for not-selected
    private ArrayList<String> ratedCallsList;
    private CallDataHelper cdh;

    public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
        selectedPos = pos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public int getSelectedPosition(){
        return selectedPos;
    }

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.mList = list;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        try{

            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);    // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
            }

            // setting STRIP BG         
            if(position == selectedPos){
                view.findViewById(R.id.rlt_main).setBackgroundColor( Color.rgb(062, 076, 120) );
            }else if(position%2==0){
                view.findViewById(R.id.rlt_main).setBackgroundColor( Color.rgb(226, 231, 239) );
            }else{
                view.findViewById(R.id.rlt_main).setBackgroundColor( Color.rgb(200, 210, 223) );
            }   

            setViews(position, view);

        }catch(Exception e){
            //Log.i(MyListAdapter.class.toString(), e.getMessage());                
        }
        return view;
    }   

    public void setViews(int position, View view) {         

        cdh = new CallDataHelper(mContext);

        if(mContext.getClass().equals((RatedCalls.class))){

            ratedCallsList = this.cdh.selectTopCalls();
            Log.i("MYLISTADAPTER", "size " + ratedCallsList.size());
            if (ratedCallsList != null) {

                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name)).setText(ratedCallsList.get(0));
                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_number)).setText(ratedCallsList.get(1));
                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).setText(ratedCallsList.get(2));
                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(ratedCallsList.get(3));
            }

        }else if(mContext.getClass().equals(RatedContacts.class)){

            final PublishersBO listPublisher = (PublishersBO) mList.get(position);
            if (listPublisher != null) {
                //--setting list_item views
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name)).setText(listPublisher.getName());
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_number)).setText(listPublisher.getEmail());
                //--onClickListener
                view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext,RatedContacts.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("NAME", listPublisher.getName());                                                     
                        myIntent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_NAME", mContext.getClass().toString());
                        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
                        mActivity.finish();
                    }
                });
            }

        }       
    }
}
```

The method that retrieve the data from the database is in a separated class that deals with SQLite function. This is the method:

```
public ArrayList<String> selectTopCalls() {

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null,
            "duration desc");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {                
            //if (cursor.getString(2) != "") {

                cdObj = new CallData();

                list1.add(cursor.getString(2));
                list1.add(cursor.getString(4));
                list1.add(cursor.getString(5));
                list1.add(cursor.getString(6));                     

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list1;
}
```

And here is the xml file for the view named **list_item.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="67px" 
android:id="@+id/rlt_main"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_forward">

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/iv_forward" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</ImageView>                

<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/phone_number" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_forward"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_forward">
</TextView> 

<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/duration" 
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phone_number"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone_number"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/date" 
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/contact_name"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/contact_name" 
    android:textSize="20px" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_forward"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</TextView>
```

So I'd like to print the data in the text views in the activity, but I dont know where to set the text, in what class, if in the MyListAdapter class or if in the activity.

Thanks.

Comment: I did something similar, but making my "MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter" and then using "bindView" find and set the text element for each list item.  (I can share that method if you'd like)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made few changes to your code, check here, 
https://gist.github.com/683b84af9d01bf18fe3d

Thanks.........